# PDO returns false instead of empty array

Tags: php, pdo

I am using PHP 7.4 and my class have a function that should return an array. But if the row is empty it returns false instead of an empty array. That is why I get an error message:

> Return value must be of type array, bool returned

```
private function getCartItem(int $sku): array
{
    $statement = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM pbo_cartItem WHERE cartId = ? AND sku = ?");
    $statement->execute(array($this->cartId, $sku));
    return $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Comment: [`fetch()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) returns `false` on failure, like when there are no available rows.  It's up to you to handle this and generate a blank array if you need it.  Something like `return $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ?: [];`.  Also note that `fetch()` only returns *one* (the next) row.  If you have multiple rows, you need to keep calling `fetch()` until it returns `false` (meaning you ran out of rows).  Did you want [`fetchAll()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`PDOStatement::fetch()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) method returns `false` if there are no more rows in the result set.

To overcome this error message, provide an empty array as a default value in case no rows were found.

```
return $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ?: [];
```